# php generated images not showing in webview

Tags: php, android, webview

I have an android app with a webview.
Within the webview i have some php generated images (GDLIB)

```
<!-- Show a php generated image from GDLIB -->
<img src='graphs/graph.php'>

<?
// Graph.php
$src = imagecreatefrompng('mapStatus.png');
$dstC = imagecreatefromgif('pointClosed.gif');
$text_color=ImageColorAllocate($src,255,255,255);
imagecopymerge($src,$dstC,22,15,0,0,4,4,95);
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($src);
imagedestroy($src);
?>
```

For some reason these images, are not being shown within the webview, while they work fine in a regular browser window.
Replacing the path with a non-php generated image works fine.

Is there some workaround, so that I may be able to show php generated images in webview ?

EDIT:
Webview shows a broken image like this:

[image: Webview broken image]

instead of the actual picture that should look like this:

[image: Actual picture]

Thank you

Comment: Please show the php script.

Comment: Please try without lines two, three and four. And change `'Content-type:` to `'Content-Type:.`

Comment: Tried:
header('Content-Type: image/png');
$src = imagecreatefrompng('mapStatus.png');
imagepng($src);
imagedestroy($src);
but with same result. Android still shows a broken image while it works fine in any browser

Comment: `Android still shows a broken image` ??? you first said that WebView didn't display the images.

Comment: Yes within webview a broken image [like this](http://i59.tinypic.com/2j4zwvr.png) is shown instead of the actual picture

Comment: I see no broken image on tinypic. Only a nasty ad and windows opening here and ther. What a mess.

Comment: Please also post the normal image too as i do not know where to look at. I tried your code and it works for me. I will retry with your image if you post the original mapStatus.png

Comment: Terrible how you describe your problem. WebView does not show your image broken but displays its own 'file not found' or  'file corrupted' icon.

Comment: Is `H4dij.png` the same as `mapSatus.png` ? byte for byte? If not it makes no sense that i do a test with it.

Comment: My apologies. Describing is not my best feature. I did some further testing and found that if i used the full image path (http.....php) WITHOUT https, the image will show. However using https it will not

Comment: So the page is loaded with https?

Comment: Yes it is, but for some reason, using https in the image path is not accepted, even though the ssl cert is fine. Thank you for your time though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

- Double-checking your relative URL.
- Specifying headers.

  header('Content-Type: image/png');

With that above your image output, your browser won't have to assume the content type, which it may be doing.

Check your console for 40X/500 errors and "expected type image/png but received text/html" or similar.